# How to set up a heterogenous topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm currently trying to set up some integration tests around a Kafka consumer solution. I've got this working fine for homogenous topics, but the test also requires me to set up a heterogenous topic and I can't seem to specify the schema correctly.

What I've done, inside the control panel, is to create an array of record schemas like this:

```
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "name": "TestRecord",
    "namespace": "my.test",
    "type": "record"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "bar",
        "type": "long"
      }
    ],
    "name": "TestRecordToo",
    "namespace": "my.test",
    "type": "record"
  }
]
```

When I push messages through this topic using a custom writer we've made for the purpose, Kafka versions this array. The original array becomes v1 and the two values become v2 and v3, so only the final message format is actually transmitted.

How do I configure my local instance with a schema that will hold two different message formats inside a topic?

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer the question - Kafka itself doesn't care what's in the topic.

Schemas can only be one message format. Sending an array doesn't register multiple schemas (at least in my experience, we always registered on individual records). That being said, the format that's sent to the topic or registered shouldn't be the "final one" in the array , but rather the format the producer serializer actually used.

If you use a new format, then that's a new version, but it doesn't alter previously sent data in the topic since Kafka records are immutable.

But versions are only assigned per subject. If you truly wanted differing schemas in a topic, not just backwards compatible modifications to the same one, you'll need to change the [Subject Strategy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#subject-name-strategy).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with Union types. See: [Putting Several Event Types in the same Topic](https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/).

Comment: Note that linked content is not considered part of an answer on StackOverflow. Your answer might hence be perveived and judged as "This is possible with Union types."; which is an answer, but not a very detailed one.